# Display inside table person from arrray

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 arrays, first one contain Company details, second person details. What I want is to display inside table each person from Company array.

```
//Table Data 
      const **CompanyData** = [
        {id: 1, name: 'Company1', phone: 'Phone1', address: 'Miron1', persons: [1,2]},
        {id: 2, name: 'Company2', phone: 'Phone2', address: 'Miron2', persons: [1]},
        {id: 3, name: 'Company3', phone: 'Phone3', address: 'Miron3'}
      ]
 

  //Person Data
  const **PersonData** = [
    {id: 1, firstName: 'a', lastName: 'b', phone: 'phone1', address: 'Miron1'},
    {id: 2, firstName: 'c', lastName: 'd', phone: 'phone2', address: 'Miron2'},
    {id: 3, firstName: 'e', lastName: 'f', phone: 'phone3', address: 'Miron3'}
  ]

//Filter Person

CompanyData.forEach((company) => {
    if(company.persons) {
      company.persons = company.persons.map((member) => {
        return PersonData.filter((person) =>{
          return person.id === member
        })
      })
    }
  })
```

How can I display inside table on specific row, any information about person from Company array.

Comment: How do you want to display the data? Because there are many options here... For example you can either display the data in the table, extending the columns to display each person belonging to a Company, or simply show the person info inside a floating popup when hovering the row of a Company. If you specify a bit more I can write a proper answer.

Comment: I want to display each person details inside table row. Like this. <td> {person.firstName}, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your filtering function couldn't work, so please take a look at my snippet below:

```
  const people = companyData
    .filter((company) => company.persons)
    .map((el) =>
      el.persons.map(
        (el, i) => el === personData[i].id && <div key={i}>{personData[i].firstName} {personData[i].lastName}</div>
      )
    )
```

And put `{people}` to your render method.

I have displayed only first and lastName. If you want you can create th, tb and so on or make the same using divs and have fun with css. Remember that table isn't responsive, so I recommend using some divs.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my solution. This is one of the ways to accomplish this task.

https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-mcnulty-kimpk?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

I recommend you use functional programming to keep the code clean and tidy. You have changed data inside the array "CompanyData", which can make debugging difficult later.